# Session id on a CallBackUrl page keeps changing

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, database, api

I'm sending a request to an API that sends back a response to a page/url (response.php).  Details from this response are stored in a db table as well as the page's session id. Obtaining the data stored in the db with the session id as the reference value returns `null` because I noticed the session id sent to the db alongside the response body changes each time making it different to session ids from all other pages in the folder (processor.php, app.js, fromdb.php) which are similar each other. How do I handle the issue seeing as I need the device from which the button that initiated the process got clicked to be able to receive an alert with some details based on data saved to db, on whether their payment was successful or not.

The js page that initiates action when a button is clicked:

```
if (document.readyState == 'loading') {
    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded',ready);
}else{
    ready()
}

function ready() {
        var btn = document.getElementById('sub')
        btn.addEventListener('click',btnClicked)
        console.log("ready")
}

function btnClicked() {
    let amount = document.getElementById('Amt').value;
    let phone = document.getElementById('Number').value;
    let name = document.getElementById('Name').value;
    //using ajax post data
            $.ajax({
                url: "http://localhost/textEditor/processor.php",
                method: "POST",
                data: {
                        amount: amount,
                        phone: phone,
                        name: name
                    },
             });

    getResult();

  }

async function getResult() {
 //using ajx Get method to obtain data from db echoed on fromdb.php page
    return await setTimeout($.ajax({
            url: "http://localhost/textEditor/fromdb.php",
            method: "GET",
            success: function(data) {
                console.log("The data is:", data)
          }
         }), 5000)

}
```

Below is page that makes request to the API and provides callbackurl on which response is sent:

```
<!-- processor.php -->
<?php 
session_start();
$sess_id = session_id();
include_once "db.te.php";

// if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
        
    date_default_timezone_set('Africa/Nairobi');

    $Passkey = 'bfb279f9aa9bdbcf158e97dd71a467cd2e0c893059b10f78e6b72ada1ed2c919';

    $Amount= $_POST['amount'];
    $BusinessShortCode = '174379';
    $PartyA =$_POST['phone'];
    $AccountReference =$_POST['name'];
    $TransactionDesc = 'test';
    $Timestamp =date('YmdHis');
    $Password = base64_encode($BusinessShortCode.$Passkey.$Timestamp);
    $headers=['Content-Type:application/json; charset=utf8'];
    $initiate_url='https://sandbox.safaricom.co.ke/mpesa/stkpush/v1/processrequest';
    $callBackURL ='https://c28d-197-231-178-65.ngrok.io/textEditor/response.php';
    // ------------------------------

function newAccessToken() {
        $ConsumerKey = 'uhsjjsjbVGatHuJKK';
        $ConsumerSecret = 'Yh29KHAY17LKjahh';
        $credentials = base64_encode($ConsumerKey.":".$ConsumerSecret);
        $url = "https://sandbox.safaricom.co.ke/oauth/v1/generate?grant_type=client_credentials";
        $curl = curl_init();
       curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
       curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("Authorization: Basic ".$credentials,"Content-Type:application/json"));
       curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
       curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
       $curl_response = curl_exec($curl);
       $access_token=json_decode($curl_response);
       curl_close($curl);
       return $access_token->access_token;
   }

    $curl = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $initiate_url);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type:application/json','Authorization:Bearer '.newAccessToken()));
    $curl_post_data = array(
        'BusinessShortCode' =>$BusinessShortCode,
        'Password' => $Password,
        'Timestamp' => $Timestamp,
        'TransactionType' => 'CustomerPayBillOnline',
        'Amount' => $Amount,
        'PartyA' => $PartyA,
        'PartyB' => $BusinessShortCode,
        'PhoneNumber' => $PartyA,
        'CallBackURL' => $callBackURL,
        'AccountReference' => $AccountReference,
        'TransactionDesc' => $TransactionDesc
    );

    $data_string = json_encode($curl_post_data);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data_string);
    $curl_response = curl_exec($curl);

       curl_close($curl);
 // }
```

The callbackurl page where response is sent and inserted into db:

```
<!-- callbackurl: response.php, page where response body is sent to the db alongside its session id-->
<?php 
include_once "db.te.php";
session_start();
$sess_id = session_id();

    $homepage =  file_get_contents('php://input');
    $nowNow = json_decode($homepage);

      if ($nowNow->Body->stkCallback->ResultCode==0) {
        $Items = $nowNow->Body->stkCallback->CallbackMetadata->Item;
        foreach($Items as $Item) {
            if ($Item->Name =='MpesaReceiptNumber') {
                $MpesaReceiptNumber = $Item->Value;
            }
        }
     }else{
        $ResultCode = $nowNow->Body->stkCallback->ResultCode;
        $MerchantRequestID =  $nowNow->Body->stkCallback->MerchantRequestID;
        $CheckoutRequestID = $nowNow->Body->stkCallback->CheckoutRequestID;
        $ResultDesc = $nowNow->Body->stkCallback->ResultDesc;
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM duka;";

        $stmt = mysqli_stmt_init($conn);

        if (!mysqli_stmt_prepare($stmt, $sql)) {
                    echo "SQL statement failed 1!";

            }else{
                mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
                $result = mysqli_stmt_get_result($stmt);
                $rowCount = mysqli_num_rows($result);

                $sql = "INSERT INTO duka(ResultCode, MerchantReqID, CheckoutReqID, ResultDesc, SessionId) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?);";

                if (!mysqli_stmt_prepare($stmt, $sql)) {
                            echo "SQL statement failed 2!";

                }else{
                    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt,"sssss", $ResultCode, $MerchantRequestID,$CheckoutRequestID,$ResultDesc,$sess_id);

                    mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
                    }
        }

    }
```

Selecting data from db and sending it to the js page to be logged:

```
<!-- fromdb.php -->
<?php 
include_once "db.te.php";
session_start();
$sess_id = session_id();

//retrieving data from db where Session ID is equal to this page's session ID
    $sql="SELECT * FROM duka WHERE SessionId = $sess_id;";

        $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
        $resultCheck=mysqli_num_rows($result);

        if ($resultCheck > 0) {

            while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
                $data = $row["CheckoutReqID"];  
            }
        }
    //value to be printed using console.log following an ajax get method
        echo json_encode($data);
```

Comment: You can not expect your user session to work inside such a callback URL script - this gets requested by their servers, not by your user's browser. So there will be no cookie with a valid session ID in that request.

Answer (score 0):

If you set a cookie for the id, instead of the session, you'll be able to maintain the id in the callback url.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).